# single quotes and double quotes not inserting in datadase using php

Tags: php

i am inserting data into mysql using php it's work partialy it's inserting everything but not single quotes(') ex. principle's message. and when i insert it like principle"s message. it's inserting in database but it's only displaying principle in text box after inserting. and my file is save.php is here.

```
<?php session_start();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    if($_GET['catId'] == '' || $_GET['catId'] == null)
        header('location:../user/logout.php');
    $inc = -1;
    if($_POST['title'] == '' || $_POST['title'] == null) {
        $inc++;$_SESSION['error'][$inc] = "TITLE IS REQUIRED";
    }
    $selectImg=mysql_query("SELECT pri_img FROM aboutus_tbl WHERE id=4");
    if ($_GET['catId']==4) {
    if($_FILES["file"]["name"]) {
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);
        if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 5242880)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
            $imageNewName = md5(date("l, F d, Y h:i" ,time()) . (microtime())) . "." . $extension;
        else {
            $inc++;$_SESSION['error'][$inc] = "IVALID IMAGE";
        }
    }
    else {
        $inc++;$_SESSION['error'][$inc] = "IMAGE IS REQUIRED";
    }
    }
    function inputValues() {
        $_SESSION['values']['title'] = $_POST['title'];
        $_SESSION['values']['sub_title1'] = $_POST['sub_title1'];
        $_SESSION['values']['desc1'] = $_POST['desc1'];
        $_SESSION['values']['sub_title2'] = $_POST['sub_title2'];
        $_SESSION['values']['desc2'] = $_POST['desc2'];
        $_SESSION['values']['sub_title3'] = $_POST['sub_title3'];
        $_SESSION['values']['desc3'] = $_POST['desc3'];
        header("location:../../views/aboutus_content/list.php?catId=".$_GET['catId']);
    }
    if($inc > -1)
        inputValues();
    else {
        require_once('../../includes/connect.php');
        if($_GET['catId']==4 && isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            $update="UPDATE aboutus_tbl SET title='".$_POST['title']."',sub_title1='".$_POST['sub_title1']."',desc1='".$_POST['desc1']."',sub_title2='".$_POST['sub_title2']."',desc2='".$_POST['desc2']."',sub_title3='".$_POST['sub_title3']."',desc3='".$_POST['desc3']."',pri_img='".$imageNewName."' WHERE id='".$_GET['catId']."'";
        }
        else{
            $update="UPDATE aboutus_tbl SET title='".$_POST['title']."',sub_title1='".$_POST['sub_title1']."',desc1='".$_POST['desc1']."',sub_title2='".$_POST['sub_title2']."',desc2='".$_POST['desc2']."',sub_title3='".$_POST['sub_title3']."',desc3='".$_POST['desc3']."' WHERE id='".$_GET['catId']."'";
        }
        if(mysql_query($update)) {
            if($_GET['catId']==4 && isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"../../public/img/principal/".$imageNewName);
            unlink("../../public/img/principal/".mysql_result($selectImg, 0, "pri_img"));
            }
            $_SESSION['message'] = $_POST['title']." SUCESSFULLY UPDATED";
            header('location:../../views/aboutus_content/list.php?catId='.$_GET['catId']);
        } else {
            $_SESSION['error'] = "ERROR : '".mysql_error()."' CODE : ".mysql_errno();
            inputValues();
        }
    }
} else
    header('location:../user/logout.php')
?>
```

and designing file is here list.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
include '../../includes/header.php';
if(!isset($_GET['catId']) || $_GET['catId']=='')
    header('location:../error');
$contactResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aboutus_tbl WHERE id='".$_GET['catId']."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($contactResult) != 1)
    header('location:../error');
else { 
?>
<div class="mainbar">
<div class="page-head">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <h2><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> <?php echo mysql_result($contactResult, 0, "title");?> Content</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
            echo"<div class='alert alert-danger'>";
                for($i=0;$i<sizeof($_SESSION['error']);$i++)
                    echo "<p><b>".$_SESSION['error'][$i]."</b></p>";
            echo"</div>";
            unset($_SESSION['error']);
        }
        if(isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
            echo"<div class='alert alert-success'><p><b>".$_SESSION['message']."</b></p></div>";
            unset($_SESSION['message']);
        }
    ?>
    <div class="hide alert alert-danger" id="errorContainer"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <form action="../../controllers/aboutus_content/save.php?catId=<?php echo $_GET['catId'];?>" method="post" class="contactForms" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="title"><span class="text-danger">* </span>Title</label>
                        <input name="title" id="title" data-validation-allowing="'" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Title" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['values'])) echo $_SESSION['values']['title']; echo mysql_result($contactResult, 0, "title");?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="sub_title1"><span class="text-danger">* </span>Sub Title 1</label>
                        <input name="sub_title1" id="sub_title1" data-validation-allowing="'" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Sub Title 1" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['values'])) echo $_SESSION['values']['sub_title1']; else echo mysql_result($contactResult, 0, "sub_title1");?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="desc1"><span class="text-danger">* </span>Description 1</label>
                        <textarea name="desc1" id="desc1" data-validation-allowing="'" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Description 1"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['values'])) echo $_SESSION['values']['desc1']; else echo mysql_result($contactResult, 0, "desc1");?></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="sub_title2"><span class="text-danger">* </span>Sub Title 2</label>
                        <input name="sub_title2" id="sub_title2" data-validation-allowing="'" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Sub Title 2" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['values'])) echo $_SESSION['values']['sub_title2']; else echo mysql_result($contactResult, 0, "sub_title2");?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="desc2"><span class="text-danger">* </span>Description 2</label>
                        <textarea name="desc2" id="desc2" data-validation-allowing="'" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Description 2"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['values'])) echo $_SESSION['values']['desc2']; else echo mysql_result($contactResult, 0, "desc2");?></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="sub_title3"><span class="text-danger">* </span>Sub Title 3</label>
                        <input name="sub_title3" id="sub_title3" data-validation-allowing="'" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Sub Title 3" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['values'])) echo $_SESSION['values']['sub_title3']; else echo mysql_result($contactResult, 0, "sub_title3");?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="desc3"><span class="text-danger">* </span>Description 3</label>
                        <textarea name="desc3" id="desc3" data-validation-allowing="'" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Description 3"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['values'])) echo $_SESSION['values']['desc3']; else echo mysql_result($contactResult, 0, "desc3");?></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pri_img"><span class="text-danger">* </span>Principle Image(Only For Principal's Message)</label>
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Save" />
                    <a href="list.php" class="btn btn-default">Reset</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.aboutus_content').addClass('current');
        $('.aboutus_content').addClass('open');
        $(".courImgItm<?php echo $_GET['catId']?>").addClass('active');
    });
}
</script>
<?php
include '../../includes/footer.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['values']))
    unset($_SESSION['values']);
ob_flush();
?>
```

please help me.

Comment: Stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` calls, learn about SQL injection and prepared statements. A good place to start is [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: have you tried escaping your single or double quotes before insertion?

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki please don't advise bad solutions. He really should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

Run your string through this first:

mysql_real_escape_string($string);

It'll fix it for ya

Comment: This deprecated and wrong. Please don't do this. Learn about prepared statements.

Comment: What would you use? bart

Comment: As I said. Prepared statements, using PDO.

Comment: ok.it's working for insertion but what for displaying like principle"s message in text box now it's only displaying principle.

Answer (score 0):

try using this way
in your sql  query---

```
$m1=$_REQUEST['message'];
$msg='".str_replace("\"","&quot;",str_replace("'","''",$m1))."';
```

hope this will help

Comment: $m1 is your messge  you want to insert ....i already checked it and from this way you can easily insert your single quote....